# Connection refused in Dockerfile but not when execed in

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a command that calls a local docker container server.

I use `docker-compose run name_of_service /bin/bash` to exec into an image and from there calling command below works as expected.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi --extra-index-url http://pypi:8000 -r requirements.txt
```

But running virtually the same command in Dockerfile results in a Retrying error

```
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi --extra-index-url http://pypi:8000 -r requirements.txt --user
```

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f54bac2dad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /custom-utils/
```

Both services are in one docker-compose.yml

Yaml

```
  service:
    image: service:20.10.1
    build:
      context: platform
      dockerfile: service/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - api
      - pypi
    environment:
      PORT: "8088"
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    volumes:
      - some_location_of_source
    restart: always

  pypi:
    image: pypi:20.10.1
    build:
      context: services/pypi
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      PORT: "8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - some_location_of_source
```

Comment: are they in the same docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Stefano Yes in the same.

Comment: Is it possible to add the two versions of the yaml?

Comment: Added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile `RUN` instructions can never make network calls to other services, even in the same `docker-compose.yml` file.  You need to arrange for the package server to run "somewhere else" (even in Docker but launched separately might work).

At a technical level there are two issues.  Compose broadly gets to assume all image builds happen before any containers are launched, so there's no way to require the `pypi` service to start before the `service` image is built (`depends_on:` doesn't affect the build stage).  Image builds also aren't attached to the Docker network that Compose creates, so they can't do things like resolve container hostnames; that will lead to the specific error you're getting.

It might work to split this into two separate Compose YAML files, one for the package server and one for the main service.  You can launch the package server; then `docker-compose build` the main service; then stop the package server.  Since you have published `ports:` you can reach the package server through one of the host's IP addresses; or if you're on a MacOS or Windows host, the special host name `host.docker.internal`; or otherwise use one of the techniques described in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=1).

```
RUN pip install \
  --extra-index-url http://host.docker.internal:8000 \
  -r requirements.txt
```

(Depending on what exactly is in this package server, you may not need it at all.  If you `python setup.py bdist_wheel` or `pip wheel` the dependencies you keep there, you can `COPY` the resulting `.whl` files into your image and install them directly.  If it's all from the same source tree then a multi-stage build where earlier stages just build libraries could work too.)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! My plan is to have this service deployed to a website and have that be called, but I haven't gotten it yet so was doing it locally.
About COPYing wheels, there's a command to upload a wheel to a remote repository which I find easier than moving them to the server or doing that inside of the package.